# Centralized to Decentralized (Is it transferable?)

Tags: ether

I do not know much about Blockchain tech, but it seems like it's the future. However, what happens to everything that already exists?

E.g., would an existing domain registrar be able to transition to be part of Blockchain or things such as Ethereum?

Lets say there's a social network with 5,000 members. Would the admin be able to transfer the entire website from Hosting Provider Whatever to Blockchain? If so, do you think traditional domains get transferred over one day too?

For example, what happens to a huge company like GoDaddy? What happens to the .com, .net, and .org extension? Does all of this transfer to Blockchain tech? If not, is everyone in the existing WWW going to lose business?

As of now, Ethereum is using a .org extension that was issued by some sort of centralized company who sells .org domains no? How is this all going to work??

I'd hate to see premium .com domains have 0 value if it can no longer be used to what everyone will soon (possibly) adapt to.

I hope I made sense. SUPER important question for a tonnnnnn of reasons, and people.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too speculative for this board. Anything _might_ happen. :-)

Comment: May you post this question to https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/